# C++: how to store a sorted set of tuples?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Using GCC 4.x, g++ and STL. Which internal structure should be used to hold such array: `(  (1,4), (2,8), (3,7) )`? It should have static element numbers to keep the original (as added) order.

Variants:

- set<map(int,int)>
- array<map>
- array {array[2], array[2]}

Can this be done with vectors in a better looking way?

Comment: Is the first element for each pair its index? I.e., are the pairs always ordered by their first element?

Comment: the pairs should retain the order, in which they were added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::set` holding std::pair is what first comes to mind

however this might not comply with this requirement:

> It should have static element numbers
>   to keep the original (as added) order.

Comment: std::set holding std::pair is exactly std::map !

Comment: @Alexandre No, it is not - an `std::map` does not order by the second pair element, while the `std::set` does.

Comment: @ltjax: hmmm... you're right. It's a more like std::multimap then.

Comment: @Alexandre No, it's also not like a multimap - which just allows duplicates with respect to the key-type (first pair element). It'll still not order by the second pair element.

Comment: @ltjax: yes, I understand it, but OP did not specify he wanted the list to be sorted with respect to the second element. The only difference is that multimap will allow duplicate pairs, whereas set<pair> will not.

Comment: Ok then. Actually, I understood the question to be exactly about that. The "keep the original order" bit seemed like he wanted to add the second element for the purpose of maintaining a stable order.

Answer (score 5):

If it's already sorted, then a `vector<pair<int, int> >` makes more sense as it will allow you to preserve the insert order (which will be sorted order anyway!). Question is whether you want to sort on insert or not?

Answer (score 2):

It totally depends on your insertion/extraction use-case. In any case, you should use `std::pair` or `boost::tuple` as your element type, as they already implement the lexicographical ordering you want.

As for the container and insertion/extraction: Can you live without random-access? Do you need access to all elements (use `std::set`) or just the top (use `std::priority_queue` with `std::vector`)? If you need random access, use a bare `std::vector`: are you inserting individual elements? Then it depends on how you extract: all elements, once, after you're done inserting? Just use `push_back` and `std::sort` when you are done. Or are you extracting a lot? Then keep the array sorted by using `std::vector::insert` and `std::lower_bound`.

Comment: Note that in the case of insert-all and then extract-all, you might get away without your static insertion-counter, if you you want is to make the whole thing stable. You can just use `push_back` and `std::stable_sort`.